# e.preventDefault(); & then continue to submit and post form

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK firefox is not letting registering my onclick event...so i have to use the e.preventDefault(); my problem is i am submitting (post) vars to the form and as a result my page cannot continue to reload.....

how can i work around this?

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#submit" ).click(function(e)  {
              e.preventDefault();
             $.post()             
        .done(function( data ) {
//here I need to disable  e.preventDefault(); and carry on & post submission as normal....
                    }); 
        });
    })
```

Comment: Why are you using `$.post()` at all if you want it to continue on with form submission? Anyway, by the time the `.done()` callback runs the click handler has already finished, so it can't carry on. Have you tried calling `.submit()` on the form element at that point?

Comment: Im using ..if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")

Comment: the post function is for my 3rd party CRM...working fine in chrome

Comment: <form id="register1">  ... i could use document.register1.submit();

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.done(function( data ) {
    $('#formId').submit();  // It will submit the form which is previously halted by e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Sounds great!! and don't stop the chain of up-votes and accept the answer if it works for you :P

Comment: ahh dude... still having issues,, do u have im? i have a job for u if u can fix for me :)

Comment: I have a job for u if u? like?

Comment: skype? or IM? i will pay u too fix my page for me

Comment: Give me your email id **gmail id** here rest we can discuss it there.

Comment: Or any email id do you have?

Comment: kudikaniz[at]88clean.pro send me your skype to this disposable

Comment: Will ping you in the evening and discuss it their, if its fine with you?

Comment: thank you; i think i need the functioning maybe re written using CURL.... talk soon